pxe client just doesn't download file
I have set up a pxe-server and want to boot a client-host from it. I'm based on the tutorial https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall for pxe-booting a debian installer.
As we know, a pxe-server is composed of a dhcp-server and a tftp-server. Both work. When I boot the client into normal linux-os, it can obtain an ipv4-address, and download a file over tftp from the server. But when I boot to pxe, by choosing the corresponding option in boot-menu, it gets the ip-address, but does not try to download any file. I use tcpdump and 'journalctl -b0 -u tftpd' on the server, to get some info. It does not show any attemt from the client to get a file over tftp.
The most interesting point is that an other computer, an old Fujitsu Esprimo, is able to pxe-boot from that server. But I want to boot an 'HP Elite Tower 800 G9 Desktop PC', which behaves as explained before. The idea came to me that the file served might be for vintage bios and not suitable for the newer uefi. But I discarded that possibility, because there is not even an attempt from the client to download the file. But who knows, it is still thinkable.
I tried to change the bios-config (F10), because it's a plausible solution. The current status of my uefi-config is as follows
Advanced > Boot Options > Network (PXE) Boot, enabled
Advanced > Boot Options > Network Boot TFTP Window Size, has value 1
Advanced > Boot Options > UEFI Boot Order, all options except 'NETWORK BOOT: IPV4 Network' are disabled

Security > TPM Embedded Security > TPM Device, Hidden

So this is a config file for the dhcp server dnsmasq.
interface=enp0s31f6
domain=ftpdom.com
dhcp-range=192.168.0.3,192.168.0.253,255.255.255.0,1h
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,pxeserver,192.168.0.2

dhcp-host=bc:0f:f3:c4:[...],set:allowed,192.168.0.167
dhcp-ignore=#known


enable-tftp
tftp-root=/srv/tftp
pxe-service=x86PC, "PXELINUX (BIOS)", "pxelinux.0"
pxe-service=X86-64_EFI,"PXE (UEFI)","grubx64.efi"

pxe-service=2, "PXELINUX (0002-EFI)", "grubx64.efi"
pxe-service=6, "PXELINUX (0006-EFI)", "grubx64.efi"
pxe-service=7, "PXELINUX (0007-EFI)", "grubx64.efi"
pxe-service=8, "PXELINUX (0008-EFI)", "grubx64.efi"
pxe-service=9, "PXELINUX (0009-EFI)", "grubx64.efi"

The output on the client during boot is
>>>Start PXE over IPv4
   Station IP address is 192.168.0.167
PXE (UEFI)
PXELINUX (0007-EFI)


How is the DHCP server configured? Does it tell the client what to boot?

The 'group' section from /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf in the mentioned tutorial is missing indeed. I removed it to be able to start the dhcpd without error. I will try to integrate it properly, and tell what happens.
I thought that the line 'filename "pxelinux.0"' in the 'subnet' section might be enough.

Please [edit] your question to include the config file. Have you verified that pxelinux.0 is indeed the correct name?

At least next-server is needed too, in addition to filename. Well, please attach the configuration you ended up with. And, surprisingly good tool in this case is traffic capture: try tcpdump -vvnni eth0 udp port 69 to see what's happening on the wire with the protocol decode, which will tell you what DHCP server really sees from the client and what it sends (don't forget just to change eth0 to your actual NIC name).

So since you asked for the config file that I use, I got something with dnsmasq, and posted it. I sure need to study dhcp-configurations in order to understand what i'm doing.

Also I used the tcpdump command proposed by Nikita, and can start understanding the output.

Finally it works with a very simple configuration for isc-dhcp.
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.0.20 192.168.0.250;
  next-server 192.168.0.2;
  filename="/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI";
}

Hereby 192.168.0.2 is the serveraddress.
